# win_copy - Unable to copy file from Azure mapped drive to C:

Tags: ansible

I have a azure storage mapped drive mapped successfully to my VM.  I'm trying to copy a file from it to Temp folder on C: but I get the below error:

`fatal: [192.168.1.193]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "dest": "C:\\Temp\\dotNET53", "msg": "Cannot copy src file: 'Z:\\Software\\Microsoft\\dotNET3\\microsoft-windows-netfx3.cab' as it does not exist", "src": "Z:\\Software\\Microsoft\\dotNET3\\microsoft-windows-netfx3.cab"}`

Here is my code to copy the file:

```yaml
- name: Copy dotNET 3.5 CAB File to Server
  win_copy:
    src: Z:\Software\Microsoft\dotNET3\microsoft-windows-netfx3.cab
    dest: "{{ Generic_Temp_Path }}\\dotNET53"
    remote_src: true
  # vars:
  #   ansible_become: yes
  #   ansible_become_method: runas
  #   ansible_become_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
  #   ansible_become_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
```

Ive tried to play with `become` with no luck. With or without, generates the same error.

Ive logged into the VM as the ansible_user and I can see the mapped drive and access files.  `net use` is also checks out too.

Not sure if its relevant but I'm mapping the drive using the below code successfully:

```yaml
Login with service principal via oauth
- name: get sas token through oauth2
  uri:
    url: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{ lookup('env','AZURE_TENANT') }}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    method: POST
    body_format: form-urlencoded
    body: "client_id={{ lookup('env','AZURE_CLIENT_ID') }}&scope=https://management.azure.com/.default&client_secret={{ lookup('env','AZURE_SECRET') }}&grant_type=client_credentials"
    return_content: yes
  register: sas_token_info
  delegate_to: localhost

# querying storage api to get latest key
- name: get the storage account keys
  uri:
    url: "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/XXXXXXXX/listKeys?api-version=2023-01-01"
    method: POST
    headers:
      Authorization: "Bearer {{ sas_token_info.json.access_token }}"
  register: storage_account_keys
  delegate_to: localhost

# - debug:
#     msg: "{{ sas_token_info.json.access_token }}"

# - debug:
#     msg: "{{ storage_account_keys.json['keys'].0.value }}"

- name: Add storage creds & map drive 
  block:
  - name: Store creds from mapped drive
    win_credential:
      name: XXXXXXXX.file.core.windows.net
      type: domain_password
      username: localhost\XXXXXXXXX
      secret: "{{ storage_account_keys.json['keys'].0.value }}"

  - name: Map drive 
    win_mapped_drive:
      letter: Z
      path: \\XXXXXXXXX.file.core.windows.net\cmdb
    
  vars:
    ansible_become: yes
    ansible_become_method: runas
    ansible_become_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
    ansible_become_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks.